# How to stop embarassing images showing on my phone's screen when I try to tweet?

Tags: downloading, images, twitter

I have downloaded some images of an adult nature onto my phone. My problem is, they show up as preview images whenever I try to compose a new tweet in the official Twitter app. I can't find any setting to turn this behaviour off.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use an app like [Keep Safe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kii.safe&hl=en_US) to hide "adult" photos/files. This keeps other apps from being able to see/interact with them, so they won't show up in the preview section of any apps.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty file with the name "".nomedia" in that folder and new previews will be generated.